# What language tag do I use in GitHub Flavored Markdown for a .gitignore code block/excerpt?

Tags: github, markdown

I have a `README.md` in a repository on GitHub that shows a code block of an example `.gitignore`.
I know that one can mark a code block with a language tag in GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM).
For example, the following would be properly prettified in GFM:

```
json
{
  "json": true
}
```

Also, I know that the definitive list of languages supported by GFM is the [`languages.yml` in the linguist repository](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml).
However, I cannot figure out which of those language tags I should use.

I tried `gitignore` even though it isn’t on the list of supported languages, but it doesn’t get highlighting:

```
gitignore
# Common editor swap files
*.swp
*~
*\#*
```

What tag should I use in this case?

EDIT: I have opened [linguist#4225](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/4225)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been added to `linguist`: https://github.com/github/linguist/pull/4343

The tag you should use is `ignore-list`, as in

````
```ignore-list
# Common editor swap files
*.swp
*~
*\#*
```
````

[Apparently](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/4225#issuecomment-758154728) it also supports `gitignore` as an alias for `ignore-list`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `INI` so your comment is in green, while the rest is black. Unfortunately, that also shows green on your fourth line. It's the closest match AFAIK.

Perhaps you can insert a [new feature request](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues).

Comment: If going for a closest match, I think `sh` would be a better suggestion. As you mentioned, the `#` on my fourth line is misinterpreted by `ini` but looks good on sh: https://gist.github.com/binki/7e0710d92863276ba39091cb299725bd